# Creating multiple profiles under one user to assign to particular posts

Tags: custom-post-types, users, user-meta, profiles

I am working with WP Job Manager at the moment quite a lot and currently on each job you would like to post you enter a set of details about the company the job is with.

This info is then echoed out onto the particular job advert it is associated with.

In most cases I can see how this default behavior covers most bases and the info is stored ready for the next job saving the same info from been entered over and over again.

For my first step in a change of process I would like have these fields attributed to the user specifically, for example as part of their user profile. I have used ACF on a little test site locally and added a couple of fields to the user and with a little more work will get them echoed out onto each page... I hope.

What I would really like to do is allow the user to visit their "profile" on the front end of the site and be able to edit this info, rather than me go into the back end each time and do it for them.

So end result here is they set up their profile and each time they post a job it brings in the unique job details and their company profile.

The next step along the way, if it is even possible is to allow the user to have multiple profiles that they can then attribute specific jobs to.

The reason for this is that the people doing the posting are from the recruitment team based at the large owner company and they post all they jobs on job sites for their trading names of that company.

e.g. - Large PLC - Job Poster Posting Jobs
     -- Small Business - Job Poster Posts My Jobs
     -- Another Small Business - Job Poster Posts My Jobs

So the "Super User" can post a job and pick which little business that job is for and hay-presto it contains all the details from that company profile they had set up :)

Sorry for the long question but it is going to be a long development starting with the singular profiles first and then moving forward.

Any advice or plugins to point me to would be great!!

Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like "Profiles" should be a custom post type with custom fields. You can then relate the profiles to the users via a custom taxonomy or even more crudely by just storing the Profile post ids as meta data of the User. This would give you the flexibility of offering multiple profiles for a single user.

Creating a form on the frontend would then capture their changes and match it to the custom fields of the Profile post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, I was mulling over the option last night and did wonder if something of this nature was possible but I think I went of track  little bit.

I have started the project this morning and will lift it to github if I get to a stable release point :)